# Calculating the total and taking the average of numbers in an array

Tags: c#

Here is the question i need to solve:

1. Find highest value of the 12 scores
2. Find lowest value of the 12 scores
3. Calculate the total of the 12 scores
4. Subtract highest and lowest scores from the total
5. Calculate average of 10 remaining scores by dividing total by 10
6. Output average (formatted to 2 decimal places)

This is what i have done so far,everything except the calculate total score and subract highest and lowest from total score and im not sure where im suppose to put the code and what code I'm suppose to use:

double[] scores = { 8.7, 9.3, 7.9, 6.4, 9.6, 8.0, 8.8, 9.1, 7.7, 9.9, 5.8, 6.9 };

```
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers in the list:" + scores.Length);

        for (int index = 0; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scores[index]);
        }


        //highest number
        double high = scores[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            if (scores[index] > high)
            {
                high = scores[index];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Highest number =" + high);

        //lowest number
        double low = scores[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            if (scores[index] < low)
            {
                low = scores[index];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("lowest number =" + low);

        //average of the scores
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + scores[index];
        }

        average = (double)total / scores.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("Total=" + total);
        Console.WriteLine("Average=" + average.ToString("N2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: As you see, it's not very difficult to do with Linq, but before answering, I'd like to know how you want to handle the fact that there might be more than one item in the list with the max/min value. In this case, would you want to remove all the items with the max or min value ?

Comment: i've been able to do everything else but i cant seem to be able to get the total minus the highest and lowest number:                this is the actual question:                                                      
Find highest value of the 12 scores 
Find lowest value of the 12 scores 
Calculate the total of the 12 scores 
Subtract highest and lowest scores from the total 
Calculate average of 10 remaining scores by dividing total by 10 
Output average (formatted to 2 decimal places)

Comment: If the values are guaranteed to be unique, then the proposed solutions here will work. On the other hand, let's say that 9.9 appears twice in the list, then your question doesn't specify how to handle it. We have to assume that it means "take only one of the highest, and one of the lowest out of the sum".

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 3.5+ , you can use LINQ [`Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Min()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functions. To do this you need to add `using System.Linq;`

```
double[] scores = { 8.7, 9.3, 7.9, 6.4, 9.6, 8.0, 8.8, 9.1, 7.7, 9.9, 5.8, 6.9 };
double calculatedValue = scores.Sum() - scores.Max() - scores.Min();
```

Comment: He said "minus the highest and lowest number"

Comment: @LucMorin Yep! Missed that for the first post, edited the solution :)

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here at all, but this could be done in a single loop

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] scores = { 8.7, 9.3, 7.9, 6.4, 9.6, 8.0, 8.8, 9.1, 7.7, 9.9, 5.8, 6.9 };
double min = scores.Min();
double max = scores.Max();
double total = scores.Sum();
double result = total - min - max;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'd like to propose a solution that will handle the case where there might be more than one element in the array with the max value or min value:

```
double[] scores = { 8.7, 9.3, 7.9, 6.4, 9.6, 8.0, 8.8, 9.1, 7.7, 9.9, 5.8, 6.9, 9.9, 5.8 };
var resultValue = scores.Where(e => e != scores.Max() && e != scores.Min()).Sum();
```

Cheers

NOTE: Yes, it might become inefficient if the list is long, as e.Max() and e.Min() will be called many times, and they will iterate the whole list many times. But according to the problem statement, there's only 12 values. I wanted to leave it as a 1 liner, but if more values were to be handled, then caching the Max and Min values would be better.